# Select column names from more multiple table names

Tags: database, postgresql-9.1

When I try

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name= ('TableA')
```

it works fine, but when I try to do the same for selected tables in the same DB it doesn't work.

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name= ('tableA', 'TableB')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your query should be:`select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = ('tableA') or table_name = ('TableB')` or maybe `select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name in ('tableA','TableB')` but not sure if postgresql support the 2nd one.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html:

> **expression IN (value [, ...])** is a shorthand notation for **expression = value1 OR expression = value2 OR ...**

(emphasis mine)

So you can use both

```
where table_name = ('tableA') or table_name = ('TableB')
```

as Gi1ber7 suggests and

```
where table_name in ('tableA','TableB')
```

- the above are equal.

If you want to use `=` operator, consider using `ANY(ARRAY)`:

```
where table_name = ANY(ARRAY['tableA','TableB'])
```

or even ANY(subquery):

```
where table_name = ANY(VALUES ('tableA'),('TableB'))
```